# bundle.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined at bundle.js:2

Tags: reactjs, webpack, bundle

I'm getting this error when i try to build a webpage using react and webpack. This is my bundle.js file.

```
var appRoot = "/";
var Builder = require('systemjs-builder');

// optional constructor options
// sets the baseURL and loads the configuration file
var builder = new Builder("/", 'config.js');

function build(entry, output) {
    var message = entry + " --> " + output;
    var begin = new Date();
    console.log("---- Build started @ " + begin.toLocaleTimeString() + " # " + message);
    builder
    .bundle(entry, output, {
        minify: true,
        mangle: true
    })
    .then(function (output) {
        var index = 1;
        output.modules.forEach(function (m) {
            ////output.modules.sort().forEach(function (m) {
            console.log(" #" + index++ + " " + m);
        });

        logEnd(begin, message);
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log('!!! error');
        console.log(err);
        logEnd(begin, message);
        throw err;
    });
}

function logEnd(begin, message) {
    var end = new Date();
    console.log("---- Build completed @ " + end.toLocaleTimeString() +" 
    (" 

    + (end - begin) + " ms) # " + message);
    }


build(appRoot + 'app.js', __dirname + '/build/app-bundle.js')
build(appRoot + 'contact/module.js', __dirname + '/build/app-bundle-contact.js')
build(appRoot + 'about/module.js', __dirname + '/build/app-bundle-about.js')
```

when i search for the error i found a solution called "using externals" which didn't work. how can i solve this issue? what is the root cause of it?

Answer (score 0):

I found the root cause of this issue. it is because i copied the webpack.config.js file from internet instead of generating it from the webpack-create-config module. which in turn did not create bundle.js file with the required dependencies.

I followed [this](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/part-1-react-app-from-scratch-using-webpack-4-562b1d231e75) tutorial to install and configure webpack and run my react application.